# editText.getText().toString returns empty

Tags: java, android, textview, gettext, editview

I'm new to Android and with the help of this site I've put together this code :

java:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    String input1 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText)).getText().toString().trim();
    TextView TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    if (input1.length() == 0) {
        TextView.setText("empty");
    } 
      else {
        TextView.setText(input1);
    }

}


}
```

xml:

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:hint="text" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />
```

But the textView shows empty when I type , tried a lot of things but nothing worked .

What I'm trying to do is get the value of editText and store it in a variable so I can work with it . I used a textView to see if it works but returns empty . I want the value to be updated real time , just like Android default calculator app .

**EDIT**

For my purpose I had to put a textWatcher.

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


TextView textView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            textView.setText(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: At the time when you're getting the String is empty... Obviously you need to listen when it change...

Comment: `TextView TextView` you've named a variable the same as a class name. I think this is *technically* fine but absolutely you should never do it. At the very least declare it in camel case: `TextView textView` but you should probably call it something more descriptive.

Comment: More specific to your actual issue, your function calls appear in `onCreate`. When the activity is created, the text box *is* empty by default. You need to move your code to somewhere else. Perhaps a button press, or a change listener on the text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Selvin, a Listener for text changes in the EditText would help.

```
        TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.length() == 0) {
                    TextView.setText("empty");
                }
                else {
                    TextView.setText(charSequence);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        };
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

But please remove the Listener (`textView.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);`)
 when you're done, as there's a potential for a memory leak here.

Comment: Yes that's the solution but unfortunately you code does not work as it crashes the app , but I've made it work and I'l post the working code . Thank you .

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. I'm wondering though, what's the exception logged when the app crashes using the code above? I wonder if it's because your local variable "TextView" wasn't set, and it tried to use TextView.setText() statically. I suppose that's why you better don't name your variables the same as the class ;) By the way, the solution you added to the original answer does not remove the TextWatcher after use, that might prevent the EditText instance from being garbage collected and thus waste memory.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt cast the java file properly...

```
TextView TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

try replacing with

```
 TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Answer (score 0):

***Change your code to the following :***

```
    public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText ed;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    ed= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    TextView TextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    String input1 = ed.getText().toString().trim();

    if (input1.length() == 0) {
        TextView.setText("empty");
    } 
      else {
        TextView.setText(input1);
    }

}


}
```

Hope it works well :)